# How to make content inside a div movable with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want something like Google maps where you can move the map around in any direction while the parent div is fixed.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="parent" style="height:60px;width:60px;overflow:hidden">
    <div class="child" style="height:120px;width:120px;cursor:move">
        This is the child div
    </div>
</div>
```

What sort of method is used for this kind of technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), take a look at jQuery UI's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/):

```
$("#child").draggable();
```

This basically involves JS events like mousedown, mouseup, mousemove etc, and then calculates the offset to apply on each mousemove using the cursor delta.

For Vertical or Horizontal limit. Initialize with X or Y axis.

```
$("#child").draggable({ axis: "x" });
```

Comment: I like it, let me check the docs to limit it to vartical drag and a reasonable hight, it seems to just drag down while there's no content on top.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lucas said, use jQuery UI's draggable.

Here is what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.drag').draggable();
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent" style="height:60px;width:60px;overflow:hidden">
    <div class="drag" style="height:120px;width:120px;cursor:move">
        This is the child div
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```